# What does "the balance of this paragraph" mean in the annotated American Gods?

Tags: meaning, wording-choice, american-gods

In Gaiman's Annotated American Gods, the annotator often refers to the balance of a paragraph.

For example annotation #73 says "The balance of this paragraph does not appear in the first edition".

What does this mean?

For reference,  this is the paragraph for annotation 73:

> Shadow ran through the airport, but the doors were already closed when he got to the gate. [73] He watched the plane pull away from the gate, through the plate glass.  Then he explained his problem to the gate attendant (calmly,  quietly, politely)  and she sent him to a passenger assistance desk, where Shadow explained that he was on his way home after a long absence and his wife had just been killed in a road accident, and that it was vitally important that he went home *now*. He says nothing about prison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/balance#Noun) entry for “balance” we need sense 11 “(*law*, *business*) the remainder”, and in the *OED* we need sense 21:

> **balance, *n.1* 21.** *Commerce slang*: The remainder, the rest. Originally *U.S.*

So the annotation means that the rest of the paragraph was omitted from the first edition. The Internet Archive has a [2001 Headline edition of *American Gods*](https://archive.org/details/americangods0000gaim_j8c6) in which the paragraph ends after “glass” ([page 17](https://archive.org/details/americangods0000gaim_j8c6/page/16/mode/2up)). This indicates that in your edition, note 73 is in the wrong place: it should be after “glass”, not after “gate”.